# show different uib-alerts by using a if function ANGULARJS

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, alert, uib

How can I show different alerts by using a if function which gets its variable from nodejs backend?
In my html stands:

```
<div uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</div>
```

in my AngularJS file:

```
$http.get('/test').then(function(result){

          this.alerts =   function(){
        if(result.test != null){
                  [  { type: 'danger', msg: 'Test is false' }];
        }else{
        [  { type: 'success', msg: 'Test is right' }];
                }
              };  
}
```

But this does not work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not valid JavaScript. It would be obvious if you looked for errors in the browser console.

Here's valid code:

```
var test = false;

if (!test) {
    this.alerts = [{type: 'danger', msg: 'Test is false'}];
} else {
    this.alerts = [{type: 'success', msg: 'Test is right'}];
}
```

EDIT:

And again, in your edited code, it's still not valid JavaScript.
It should be

```
var that = this;
$http.get('/test').then(function(response) {
    if (response.data.test != null) {
        that.alerts = [{type: 'danger', msg: 'Test is false'}];
    } else {
        that.alerts = [{type: 'success', msg: 'Test is right'}];
    }
});
```

You really, really, really need to learn the basic syntax of JavaScript, and to indent your code, before even thinking playing with angular.

Comment: It works thanks. I need to surround it with a http get request to get the test value from nodejs backend. How can I make this work? Edited it above.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will.